# python: how to sort a string alphabetically and by len

Tags: python

`shakespeare = ‘All the world is a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their exits and their entrances, And one man in his time plays many parts.’`

Create a function that returns a string with all the words of the sentence shakespeare ordered alphabetically. Eliminate punctuation marks.

(Tip: the three first words should be ‘ a all all’, this time duplicates are allowed and remember that there are words in mayus)

```
def sort_string(shakespeare):
    return string_sorted
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). SO is not your assignment dump; demonstrate what you have tried and why it failed. Tldr: Basically like any other [good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Here you get a one-liner

```
import re

shakespeare = "All the world is a stage, and all the men and women merely players. They have their exits and their entrances, And one man in his time plays many parts."

print (sorted(re.sub(r"[^\w\s]","",shakespeare.lower()).split(), key=lambda x: (x,-len(x))))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'all', 'all', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'and', 'entrances', 'exits', 'have', 'his', 'in', 'is', 'man', 'many', 'men', 'merely', 'one', 'parts', 'players', 'plays', 'stage', 'the', 'the', 'their', 'their', 'they', 'time', 'women', 'world']
```

The corresponding function:

```
def sort_string(shakespeare)
    return sorted(re.sub(r"[^\w\s]","",shakespeare.lower()).split(), key=lambda x: (x,-len(x)))
```

In case you want a string to be returned:

```
def sort_string(shakespeare)
    return " ".join(sorted(re.sub(r"[^\w\s]","",shakespeare.lower()).split(), key=lambda x: (x,-len(x))))
```

Comment: Great. Will you now the mark for this homework?

Comment: OP says first three words in result should be `a all all`, so you'll want to call `shakespeare.lower()` so that capitalized words don't come first.

Comment: Check the edit schwartz. @Mr. T, well, I know. But I'm too nice.

Comment: I feel bad for overthinking this and not thinking about re...thank you

Comment: You're welcome! Please think about accepting the answer if that helped! (gray tick top left of my answer, which will turn green)